# Windows 7 Keep freezing due to potential issue with hard drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

Recently, my Windows 7 kept freezing for a long interval of time, showing me the blue spinning wheel with no BSOD. I am still able to move the windows of my current running application, so the O/S is still alive but the application freezes and I am not able to start any new processes.

I suspected that my main HDD went bad so I replaced it with a SSD, installed new copy of Windows 7 on it, but shortly after the same problem occurs. After looking at my event log, I found out that some sort of error is occuring on \Device\Ide\IdePort2.

My questions are as follows:

- How can I find out which drive is connected to IdePort2?
- What exactly is causing this issue? I suspected bad SATA cable so I replaced it but same problem happens.
- What can I do to solve this?

[image]

Comment: You need to give a LOT more information about your computer before anyone will venture an educated guess on this issue. Complete specs. List of what you have already tried.

Comment: @JoshCampbell I've already written what I have tried so far. Although I don't see how, I guess a complete spec of my computer might help. I will update my post accordingly after I get back from work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the error, I have found three possible solutions cruizing the web:

Check the channels' properties in Device Manager (should be under "IDE ATA/ATAPI controllers") to make sure they are running in Ultra DMA mode. Source: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-hardware/atapi-event-id11-the-driver-detected-a-controller/7fdd47da-7c86-4f7b-bdf7-096bb4f059f4

Check for specific drivers from the drive manufacturer (especially for the SSD). The example here cites an Intel driver package. Source: http://www.sevenforums.com/drivers/124022-event-id-11-atapi.html

Finally, this MSKB page talks about SCSI drives causing the same problem, but the advice that is applicable here is essentially to check cabling and to simplify the physical organization of drives on the cables. Source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314093